# What's wrong with my SORT function here?

Tags: mainframe, jcl, syncsort

First off, I'm a complete beginner to anything Mainframe-related.

I have a training assignment at work to find matching keys in two files using SORT.  I submitted this code to my mentor, pseudo-coded here because I can't access the system from home yet and didn't think to copy it before leaving:

```
//STEP01 EXEC SORT
//SORTIN DD DSN=file1
//       DD DSN=file2
//SORTXSUM DD DSN=output file
//SORTOUT  don't need this data anywhere specific so just tossing at spool
//SYSIN DD *
  SORT FIELDS=(1,22,CH,A)
  SUM FIELDS=NONE,XSUM
/*
```

When I stick a couple of random sequential files in, the output is exactly what I expect it to be.  However, my mentor says it doesn't work.  His English is kinda bad and I rarely understand what he's saying the first few times he repeats it.

This combined with him mentioning JOINKEYS (before promptly leaving work, of course) makes me think he just wants (needs?) it done a different way and is doing a really poor job of expressing it.

Either way, could someone please tell me whether or not the code I wrote sucks and explain why it apparently falls short of a method using JOINKEYS?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the requirement that would satisfy:

Take two unsorted datasets; match them on a 22-byte key; output all the data to one of two files. Where keys are duplicate, pick a record of the matched group, whichever is convenient to you, and which selection cannot be guaranteed to be recreated in a subsequent run, and write it to an output file; write all records not written to the first file to the second file instead.

If that is the requirement, you are on to a winner, as it will perform better than the equivalent `JOINKEYS`.

The solution can also be modified in a few ways. With `OPTION EQUALS` or `EQUALS` on the SORT statement, it will always be the *first* record of equal keys which will be retained.

For more flexibility on what is retained, `DUPKEYS` could be used instead of SUM.

If the requirement can be satisfied with SUM or DUPKEYS it is more efficient to use them than to use JOINKEYS.

If the data is already in sequence, but otherwise the requirement is the same, then it is not a good way to do it. You can try a MERGE in place of the SORT, and have a SORTIN01 instead of your SORTIN.

If you had DFSORT instead of SyncSORT, you could use ICETOOL's `SELECT` operator to do all that XSUM and DUPKEYS can do (and more).

If you are doing something beyond what SUM and DUPKEYS can do, you'll need JOINKEYS.

For instance, if the data is already in sequence, you'd specify SORTED on the JOINKEYS for that input.

On the Mainframe, resources are paid for by the client. So we aim to avoid profligacy. If one way uses fewer resources, we chose that.

Without knowing your exact requirement, can't tell if your solution is the best :-)